# Explain this code (not getting the result i need)

Tags: java, arrays

```
package javaapplication54;

public class JavaApplication54 {

static int monkey = 8;
static int theArray[] = new int[1];

public static void main(String[] args) {
// i attempted two ways to try to set monkey to = theArray[0];
    monkey = theArray[0];
    theArray[0] = monkey;
//i tried to get the result 8;
    System.out.println(theArray[0]);

}
```

}

I am trying to get the result 8, by printing out theArray[0] but the result is zero.

```
          run:
   0
 BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: don't attempt two different ways at the same time!  `theArray[0] = monkey;` is the right one.

Answer (score 2):

You assigned `theArray[0]` in the line `monkey = theArray[0]` which `theArray[0]` is `0` when you first initialized `theArray` at line:

```
static int theArray[] = new int[1];
```

Answer (score 2):

You're using `int` primitive, so it defaults to 0.

Let me break up your code piece by piece so you can understand this.

Here you state that `monkey` is 8

```
static int monkey = 8;
```

And here you create a new array

```
static int theArray[] = new int[1];
```

At this moment, the array contains only `0`, because it is the default value for `int` variables. So, `theArray[0]` is equal to `0`.

Here you got that `0` and assigned it to monkey, whose previous value was `8`

```
monkey = theArray[0];
```

And then you got that newly-assigned monkey, which now is equal to `0`, and assigned it to `theArray[0]`.

```
theArray[0] = monkey;
```

So `theArray[0]` that was equivalent to `0` is now equivalent to... yeah, `0`.

Last but not least, you print that `0` with `System.out.println(theArray[0]);`

And that's why you're getting `0` instead of `8`.

Answer (score 1):

`int` always has the value of `0` as default, so it's working as expected.

If you want it to point to `8`, save it in a temporary variable first before you assign `monkey` to somewhere else.

Answer (score 0):

line 1 in the main method replaces the value of monkey to the value stored in theArray[0] which in this case is the default int value (0).
line 2 sets the value of theArray[0] to monkey, thus the initial value of monkey(8) is completely lost.
If you want to store monkey variable in theArray[0] maybe this is what you can try,

```
public class JavaApplication54 {

static int monkey = 8;
static int theArray[] = new int[1];

public static void main(String args[])
{
theArray[0]=monkey;
System.out.println(theArray[0]);
}
```

output:- 8

Also consider the fact that both array and the variable are static , this is required because you are using them inside a static method , but if you change its value from anywhere in your code it will reflect the change everywhere.

http://www.caveofprogramming.com/java/java-for-beginners-static-variables-what-are-they/